# Get shared back buffer from SwapChain

Tags: c#, wpf, directx-11, slimdx

I have a WPF application with SlimDX control in it (DirectX 11). I create a `SwapChain` on init:

```
var description = new SwapChainDescription()
{
 ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, new Rational(60, 1), Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm)
 {
  ScanlineOrdering = DisplayModeScanlineOrdering.Unspecified,
  Scaling = DisplayModeScaling.Unspecified,
 },
 SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
 Usage = Usage.Shared | Usage.RenderTargetOutput | Usage.ShaderInput,
 BufferCount = 1,
 OutputHandle = D3DDeviceManager.SafeNativeMethods.GetDesktopWindow(),
 IsWindowed = true,
 SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
 Flags = SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch,
};
SwapChain = new SwapChain(Device.Factory, Device, description);
```

Notice, that I have a `Shared` flag set. When my window is resized, I want to update buffer size and get a new shared texture from `SwapChain`. I do it like this:

```
SwapChain.ResizeBuffers(1, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm, SwapChainFlags.None);
SharedTexture = SlimDX.Direct3D11.Resource.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(SwapChain, 0);
```

But the resulting texture has its `OptionFlags` set to `None` instead of `Shared`. Why is that? Am i doing something wrong? If I create a texture from `Texture2DDescription` it works fine.